# How to get a count for the amount of columns per row that are equal or greater than 1 in r in big data set?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in an R dataframe with organism names as the column and protein names in the rows. Each column x row gives the amount of copies of that protein found in that organisms genome.

I am trying to get a count (not sum) in a new column for each row. I want a count of every organism that has equal to or more than 1 copy of the protein. E.g. if 150 organisms have at least 1 copy, the result will be 150, not the sum total of protein count.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I have tried a variety of ifelse methods but cant seem to get it to work properly.

[image]

For example (see image above) 100596 would produce 0, 103485 would produce 7 (7 of the 9 organisms had >= 1), 104973 would produce 0 etc. Some of the datasets have hundreds to thousands of organisms by thousands of proteins, so doing this manually is unfortunately not an option.

```
structure(list(Atrsp2 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Bifad1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Rhoto1 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Ascsa1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Pirin1 = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Phisc1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Xylhe1 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Geopyr1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Mucend1 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)), row.names = c("100596", 
"103485", "104973", "112416", "116745", "125161", "12870", "15275", 
"189813"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get an actionable answer if you provide some sample data. Can you [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(x[1:10, 1:10])` (or some small size that gets the point across)?

Comment: Hi r2evans, I tried to add an example screengrab before but I don't think it worked. I have tried to attach it above now.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, but ... Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block]. (I believe most ppl will choose to not try to transcribe or OCR an image into something we can use/play-with.)

Comment: Would you be able to check this is now properly formatted r2evans? Thanks for the help, not a frequent user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowSums` is your best choice here:

```r
rowSums(quux > 0)
# 100596 103485 104973 112416 116745 125161  12870  15275 189813 
#      0      7      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
```

which can be easily added to the existing frame as:

```r
quux$newcol <- rowSums(quux > 0)
quux
#        Atrsp2 Bifad1 Rhoto1 Ascsa1 Pirin1 Phisc1 Xylhe1 Geopyr1 Mucend1 newcol
# 100596      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0
# 103485      2      0      2      1      1      1      1       0       2      7
# 104973      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0
# 112416      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0
# 116745      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0
# 125161      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0
# 12870       0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0
# 15275       0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       2      1
# 189813      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0      0
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Atrsp2 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Bifad1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Rhoto1 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Ascsa1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Pirin1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Phisc1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Xylhe1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Geopyr1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Mucend1 = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), newcol = c(0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c("100596", "103485", "104973", "112416", "116745", "125161", "12870", "15275", "189813" ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Cracking stuff, this is exactly what I needed. Can't believe it was such a small bit of code. Thanks a million, been trying to solve it for ages going round in circles. Much appreciated!!